# Is there any way to clean bin & obj directories within a solution using Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

Quite often it is necessary to delete bin & obj directories due to some weird errors, especially for Xamarin projects. I was wondering if anyone found an efficient way of dealing with it? By efficient I mean automated or semi-automated solution, so there will be no need to leave the IDE and manually delete this directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will share the solutions I found / created myself.

'DeepClean' a simple open source extension for Visual Studio for macOs which allows you to do the next things:
- Delete /bin & /obj dirs
- Delete /packages dir
- Delete global NuGet cache
- Open terminal from any solution folder

You can get it from [here](https://github.com/yuv4ik/vsmacdeepclean).

***Please use with care.***

Alternatively if you don't want to rely on extensions you could use the next [script](https://gist.github.com/yuv4ik/aedfefca352db3f149fbcb81762db847#file-dot_net_clear_bin_obj_packages_dirs-sh) which will delete all nested bin, obj and packages directories:

```
find . -iname "bin" -o -iname "obj" -o -iname "packages" | xargs rm -rf
```

If you delete the /packages directory you will have to restore the packages for solution otherwise it wont build.